# How to correctly cast to subclass in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableView` with a lot of different cells, based on whats in the content array of the datasource they should show custom content.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell : UITableViewCell? = nil
        let objectAtIndexPath: AnyObject = contentArray![indexPath.row]

        if let questionText = objectAtIndexPath as? String {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("questionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as QuestionTableViewCell
            cell.customLabel.text = "test"
        }

        return cell!
    }
```

Here I get the error that

`UITableViewCell does not have the attribute customLabel`

which `QuestionTableViewCell` does have. Whats wrong with my cast to `QuestionTableViewCell`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is not your cast but your declaration of `cell`. You declared it as an optional UITableViewCell and that declaration remains forever - and is all that the compiler knows.

Thus you must cast *at the point of the call* to `customLabel`. Instead of this:

```
cell.customLabel.text = "test"
```

You need this:

```
(cell as QuestionTableViewCell).customLabel.text = "test"
```

You could make this easier on yourself by declaring a *different* variable (since you know that in this particular case your cell will be a QuestionTableViewCell), but as long as you are going to have just one variable, `cell`, you will have to constantly cast it to whatever class you believe it really will be. Personally, I would have written something more like this, exactly to avoid that repeated casting:

```
    if let questionText = objectAtIndexPath as? String {
        let qtv = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("questionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as QuestionTableViewCell
        qtv.customLabel.text = "test"
        cell = qtv
    }
```

Comment: Or `return qtv` in the if-block and drop the `cell` variable.

Comment: @MartinR Right but I'm assuming he might not be done configuring the cell; there might be common configurations later. He has clearly shown only a tiny part of a much larger set of conditional cell configurations (for which he should be using a `switch`, not a bunch of `if` statements, but that's another story).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this `var cell : UITableViewCell? = nil`. You declare it as `UITableViewCell?` and it has that type forever.

You can declare another variable

```
let questionCell = cell as! QuestionTableViewCell
questionCell.customLabel.text = "test"
```

Answer (score -6):

you can do any one of the following:

1. replace :  `cell.customLabel.text = "test"`

   with

   ```
   cell?.customLabel.text = "text1"
   ```
2. change `var cell : UITableView? = nil` to `var cell : UITableView!`

Comment: `cell` is a `UITableViewCell` not a `UITableView`. But even then, all your proposed changes would not solve the compiler error.

Comment: Dear Martin, this is not the case, cell is actually uitableviewcell, and in this case it was a forced unwrap with ?

Comment: Yes, cell should be a UITableViewCell, but *your code* declares it as UITableView. But the problem is not the unwrapping. The problem is that the compiler does not know that `cell` has a `customLabel` property.

Comment: Martin it is understood that he is using a custom uitableviewcell and he has relevant outlets created for the custom cell, however, UITableview should be considered UITableViewCell....